# iPhone SDK: While recording in AVAudioPlayer it is also capturing background noise.Can anyone help me to reduce the background sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio-recording

We are setting recording file like this.

```
NSDictionary *settings = @{AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: @(AVAudioQualityMedium),
                               AVFormatIDKey: @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                               AVEncoderBitRateKey: @(128000),
                               AVNumberOfChannelsKey: @(1),
                               AVSampleRateKey: @(44100)};
```

Comment: i kept like that only.while copying it got replaced like that.
Can you please let me know if there is any solution to reduce the background noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code working for me.

```
audioSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100],AVSampleRateKey,
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC],AVFormatIDKey,
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMedium],AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,nil];


AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];


AVAudioRecorder *recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:tempUrl settings:audioSettings error:&error];
recorder.delegate = self;
recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
[recorder prepareToRecord];
[recorder record];
```

Comment: I am also doing like this only,But background noise is also getting recorded  .

Comment: which kind of background noise kindly explain.

Comment: it is something like water sound.

Comment: is that sound common while recording.because just now i testing for whats app.There also some little bit background sound is getting captured.but in my app its bit louder.Please let me know if you have any idea.